# " Get query missing " when crawling website

Tags: web-crawler

I tried to crawl this website https://iboard.ssi.com.vn/bang-gia/vn30 through its API.
After a while i managed to find the API url https://gateway-iboard.ssi.com.vn/graphql but when running it in my browser i got this message Get query missing .
Per my understanding , that url lacks some query string but I have no idea where i can get them. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: If `gateway-iboard.ssi.com.vn` does not provide any documentation you then need to do some reverse engineering. A starting point to do so is to look at the network tab of the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: I looked at the network and found that API url but after that I dont know how to do. I assume i have to look at headers to find something like API key or whatever. can you clarify on the "reverse engineering " part.

Comment: And besides when i enter gateway-iboard.ssi.com.vn i got 403 forbidden, does that have anything to do with me not being able to access API url.